# What is the volume of the the intersection of a sphere and a prism

Tags: calculus, geometry

all, I have a prism going through a sphere ( part of the prism is totally inside the sphere). What is the volume of the intersection? Can any one help?

Comment: You need to add more details. What is the radius of the sphere? What shape is the prism? Is the prism orthogonal to its base? What part of it intersects the sphere? ...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. The radius of the sphere is R, the base of the prism is a triangle and it's orthogonal to its base. One vertical edge of the prism go though the center of the sphere, one edge is tangent to the sphere and the third edge has a distant d (smaller than R) to the center of the sphere.

Comment: That doesn't specify the triangle completely.

Comment: if we draw a 2D plot, the three vertexes would be at the center of the circle, on the circle and inside the circle with a distance d (d <R) to the center of the circle

Comment: But there's a whole circle with that distance to the center.  What point on that circle?

Comment: The angle between the two edges going through the center of the sphere is 100 degrees.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the details you've put in the comments.  Otherwise, this question is going to be closed as "unclear what you're asking."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Let's say the three vertices are at $[0,0]$, $[R,0]$ and $[a,b]$ with $-R < a < R$, $b > 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 < R^2$.
Then the integration can be set up as
$$ 2 \int_0^b dy \int_{ay/b}^{R - (R-a)y/b} dx \; \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2} $$

This corresponds to the picture

[image]

where the left side of the triangle is the line $bx = ay$ and the right side is $b(R-x)= (R-a)y$.  The extent of the intersection of the sphere in the $z$ direction over the point $(x,y)$ in the plane is $2 \sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I don't quite understand. Can you please explain a little?

Comment: Thank you so much, I just don't quite understand the  extent of the intersection of the sphere in the z direction.

Comment: The sphere has equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$.  Thus over $(x,y)$, it goes from $z = -\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ to $z=+\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so  much for your help!  Sorry I forgot my password to log in